# Does there exist any function f(x,y) which satisfies the following condition?

Tags: functions

I would like to construct a function $f(x,y)$ such that $f(x,y)\leq 255$ for all integers $x,y\in [0,255]$ and conversely, i.e., if (x,y) is given then I can get back $x,y$ from this given $f(x,y)$. The operation may be any binary OR/XOR, or any arithmetic operation.
As for example

if $f(x,y)=x*b+y$, then for given $f(x,y)$, we can obtain $x$ and $y$ for a fixed value $b$.

Comment: Try with qbits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x$, $y$ and $f(x,y)$ are integers or integer-valued, then there are more inputs than available outputs.  By the pigeonhole principle, no such function exists.

If $f$ can be real-valued, then there are infinitely many such functions, e.g., $f(x,y) = x - 1 + y/1000000$.

Comment: According to you  $f(x,y)=2x+y$ is not posssible, but for given $f(x,y)$, we have $y=f(x,y)\%2$ and $x=f(x,y)/2$. for any integral values $x,y$@DavidG.Stork

Comment: Indeed $f(x,y) = 2 x + y$ is not possible because $x = y = 255 \rightarrow f(x,y) = 765 > 255$, and hence violates your condition on $f$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p,p+2$ and $q,q+2$ be pairs of twin primes.

$$f(x,y) = \left( \frac{p}{p+2} \right)^x \left(\frac{q}{q+2}\right)^y$$

is between $0$ and $1$.  To recover $x$ and $y$, you just have to factor the numerator of the rational number $f(x,y)$  which will be easy, because you already know all its prime factors.